# Sails node package not updating

Tags: node.js, windows, bash, sails.js

I'm currently working on a project using node and sails framework (v0.12.14). Recently Sails has updated to version 1.0.2 but I can't seem to update my own version of Sails.

I'm running bash on Windows.

I've ran the install command, which yields:

```
# npm install sails@latest -g
+ sails@1.0.2
updated 1 package in 9.947s
```

and also tried to install it in my project:

```
# npm install sails@latest --save
+ sails@1.0.2
updated 1 package in 8.941s
```

It seems to be working because when I check my npm packages, I can see it:

```
# npm ls | grep sails@
├─┬ sails@1.0.2
```

However when I try to run any new commands, such as `sails upgrade`, it fails. When I check the running version, I get:

```
# sails -v
0.12.14
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by running the command:

```
# which sails
```

Which gave me the location:

```
/usr/bin/sails
```

Afterwards I just `rm -rf`'d the directory, and reinstalled Sails globally.

After restarting my bash, it worked:

```
# sails -v
1.0.2
```